# Mousewheel scrolling inside container - catching events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, stoppropagation

I have a page with inner scrollable DIV. As I hover a mouse over it and try to scroll it with mouse wheel, the contents of that DIV is scrolled as desired while the main page stays put. But when I reach the bottom of the DIV's scrolling area, whole page begin to scroll instead.

I've tried to set event handlers on that div, but `preventDefault()` method also prevents scrolling of the DIV itself.

Here comes the wrong code:

```js
$('.folderlist').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
    ev.preventDefault();
})
```

`preventDefault()` prevents page scroll, but also disallows the scrolling of the DIV.

`stopPropagation()` does nothing in this case, I suppose

Did I miss something?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**andbeyond** came up with a nice solution, though it had issues with IE so I've tried to fix them and here you go:

```
function stopEvent(e) {
    e = e ? e : window.event;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.cancel = true;
    e.returnValue = false;
    return false;
}

$.fn.extend({
    // param: (boolean) onlyWhenScrollbarVisible
    // If set to true, target container will not intercept mouse wheel
    //     event if it doesn't have its own scrollbar, i.e. if there is too
    //     few content in it. I prefer to use it, because if user don't see
    //     any scrollable content on a page, he don't expect mouse wheel to
    //     stop working somewhere.

    scrollStop: function(onlyWhenScrollbarVisible) {
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
                if (onlyWhenScrollbarVisible && this.scrollHeight <= this.offsetHeight)
                    return;

                e = e.originalEvent;
                var delta = (e.wheelDelta) ? -e.wheelDelta : e.detail;
                var isIE = Math.abs(delta) >= 120;
                var scrollPending = isIE ? delta / 2 : 0;
                if (delta < 0 && (this.scrollTop + scrollPending) <= 0) {
                    this.scrollTop = 0;
                    stopEvent(e);
                }
                else if (delta > 0 && (this.scrollTop + scrollPending >= (this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight))) {
                    this.scrollTop = this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight;
                    stopEvent(e);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Now it does exactly what I wanted. Thanks **andbeyond** for your great blog post - http://www.andbeyonddesign.com/Blog/2012/02/Setting-scroll-only-for-scrollable-div

Example usage: `$('.folderlist').scrollStop(true);`

Comment: sweet! kudos to solving your own question

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.folderlist').hover(function (){
    $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
}, function (){
    $('body').css('overflow','auto');
})
```

try that .. guess it should work

Comment: it works, but main page scrollbar will flicker on mouseenter/mouseleave, which is not good