# Disable page scroll when some element is hovered

Tags: jquery, scroll

How can I lock window scrolling without hiding scrollbar when some block is hovered. 
And unlock window scrolling, when mouse is leaving that block?

Like here in right blue box: http://html.kudrych.ru/mosnadzor/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9989199/1411424 - It's working!
Spesial thanks to Brilliand!

Comment: Handle the `scroll` event and call `e.preventDefault()`...

Comment: In that way, I can't turn on page scrolling after mouseleave event.

Comment: Setting body{overflow} on hover() sort of works, but causes the page to jerk.

Comment: I need to disable window scrolling without hiding scrollbar.

Comment: And then I need to enable scrolling, when mouse leaved that some element.

Comment: In my example, that element is news block with own scrolling.

Comment: SUMMARY: So, when news block is howered, I need to lock window scrolling without hiding scrollbar. And unlock, when mouse is leaving that block.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977628/mousewheel-scrolling-inside-container-catching-events (There's an answer there that might do what you need, if you don't mind using a lot of JS.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the jQuery plugin [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) - it seems to handle all scrolling functions properly.  It does differ from what you want in that you have to click, not just hover, for it to supplant the main body scrollbar,but  you can change that behavior by calling focus() and blur() from hover():

```
$(".scroll-pane").hover(function() {
    this.focus();
}, function() {
    this.blur();
});
```

Comment: It's scrolling to top, when I'm hovering the block.

Comment: You don't just need a scrollbar blocking fix - you need a complete styleable scrollbar that works like a scrollbar.  I'll replace the above answer with a different one.